# Can't use variable inside of click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, jquery-click-event

I have this code and it's javaScript and jQuery:

```
for (thisLooper = 1; thisLooper < 4; thisLooper++) {

    if ($("#writeComments"+thisLooper).length > 0) {
        $("#writeComments"+thisLooper+",#comments"+thisLooper+", #infoSpan"+thisLooper+"").hide();
        $("#toggleCommentForm"+thisLooper).click(function () {
            $("#writeComments+thisLooper").slideToggle();
        });
    }

}
```

What it does:

1. Check if #writeComments1 exists
2. If it exists, hide #writeComments1, #comments1 and #infoSpan1
3. Then, if someone clicks on #toggleCommentForm1, slideToggle #writeComments1
4. Do all this for #writeComments2 and it's friends
5. Do all this for #writeComments3 and it's friends

With the code above nothing happens but if i replace:

```
$("#toggleCommentForm"+thisLooper).click(function () {
    $("#writeComments+thisLooper").slideToggle();
});
```

width this:

```
$("#toggleCommentForm"+thisLooper).click(function () {
    $("#writeComments1").slideToggle();
});
```

It all works but naturally only #writeComments1 slideToggles even if I click on #toggleCommentForm2 for instance.

My question is, why cant I use the variable "thisLooper" inside of the click events?

Comment: `$("#writeComments+thisLooper").slideToggle();` should be `$("#writeComments"+thisLooper).slideToggle();`?

Comment: ^^ you are not using it as a variable. But you could, if you would... ;)

Comment: A closure in the loop will fix it, so that the index value is retained in the callback.

Comment: The "thisLooper" variable should be concatenated with the string ("#writeComments"+thisLooper). However, He would had another problem with closures.

Comment: Sorry, had some typos below with the braces (corrected now) :)

Comment: I see the typo that you all are pointing out, thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A closure in the loop will fix the immediate problem (and put the variable outside the string of course), so that the index value is retained in the `click` callback function.

```
for (index = 1; index < 4; index++) {
    (function(thisLooper){
        if ($("#writeComments"+thisLooper).length > 0) {
            $("#writeComments"+thisLooper+",#comments"+thisLooper+", #infoSpan"+thisLooper+"").hide();
            $("#toggleCommentForm"+thisLooper).click(function () {
                $("#writeComments"+thisLooper).slideToggle();
            });
        }
    })(index);

}
```

You should also create a local `var` rather than keep re-querying the selection but I need to see your full HTML first (as the code is a little odd)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop variable is not properly closed over; instead of using a closure to fix that problem (which is what TrueBlueAussie explains in his answer), you could also consider binding the click handler to the element you wish to perform the slide on:

```
$("#toggleCommentForm"+thisLooper).click($.proxy(function () {
     // this is a jQuery object
     this.slideToggle();
}, $("#writeComments"+thisLooper));
```

Note, though, that anything more complex than just operating on a single jQuery object is better solved by a closure.